# Why does English use different prepositions for different units of time?

Tags: english, prepositions

Why do we say *at* six o'clock, *on* Monday, *in* 1996? Is there a deeper logic here than simply "that's how the English language works?"

Comment: Most uses of preposition in expressions of time are metaphors. These simply use different metaphors. A time is conceived as a POINT, a day as a SURFACE, a longer time as aCONTAINER

Comment: In a word, "No". @ColinFine is quite right; but there's no reason *why* we employ those particular metaphors with those terms; the apparent progression from 1 to 3 dimensions is subverted by our saying "at night" and "in the afternoon/morning".

Comment: @StoneyB Ah, but it's *in the night* not *at the night*, though. Just to be nitpicky ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually, the metaphors are all coherent, so there is a logic to it.

As Colin explained in his comment, and as discussed [in this post](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/92116/15299),

- Months and larger measures are Containers -- **3**-Dimensional: ***in*** 1949, **in** June, **in** this century
- Days are Surfaces -- **2**-Dimensional: ***on*** Thursday, **on** Thanksgiving, **on** this occasion
- Smaller measures are Points on a **1**-Dimensional line: ***at*** noon, **at** 12:03:45, **at** the moment

The smaller the unit of time, the fewer dimensions. Just a map location - *at Exit 37, at 2:33 pm*.
The bigger it is, the more experience it represents. A day is a page of events -- it's flat, whence *on*. 
Anything bigger than one day has to be able to stack the day pages, so it's a volume, whence *in*.

Metaphors always have an internal logic.

Comment: This is so dope